# perl-dbi #temp table created using dbh handle not accessible when accessed via ->do() with the same handle

Tags: database, perl, sql-server-2008, transactions

I am facing this problem [perl DBD::ODBC rollback ineffective with AutoCommit enabled at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6938036/perl-dbdodbc-rollback-ineffective-with-autocommit-enabled-at) and while looking at the problem , I found that a very basic thing is failing with Perl::DBI using DBD::ODBC on sql server.  But i am not sure if this wont happen with any other driver.

The problem is that when I create a #temp table using $dbh->do and when i try to access the same #temp table using another $dbh->do , i am getting the below error.  Also this does not happen all the time , but only intermittently.

Invalid object name '#temp'

```
$dbh->do("SELECT  ... INTO #temp FROM ...");
$dbh->do("INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... FROM #temp");
```

> The second do fails with  'Invalid object name '#temp''

**Kindly help me with the problem.**

Comment: Did you try setting the RaiseError flag to see if it isn't creating the table for some reason? Either that or try this (from the perldoc): $rows = $dbh->do($statement) or die $dbh->errstr;

Comment: Yes I have set both $dbh->{RaiseError} and $dbh->{PrintError} and the failure clearly is at the 2nd SQL. So 1st SQL must have created the #temp table.

Comment: Works for me. You've done the right thing using do as prepare/execute will not work as per FAQ entry at http://search.cpan.org/~mjevans/DBD-ODBC-1.31/FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not that it answers your question but it might help. The following works for me.

```
#
# To access temporary tables in MS SQL Server they need to be created via
# SQLExecDirect
#
use strict;
use warnings;
use DBI;

my $h = DBI->connect();

eval {
    $h->do(q{drop table martin});
    $h->do(q{drop table martin2});
};

$h->do(q{create table martin (a int)});
$h->do(q{create table martin2 (a int)});

$h->do('insert into martin values(1)');

my $s;
# this long winded way works:
#$s = $h->prepare('select * into #tmp from martin',
#                    { odbc_exec_direct => 1}
#);
#$s->execute;
# and this works too:
$h->do('select * into #tmp from martin');
# but a prepare without odbc_exec_direct would not work

print "NUM_OF_FIELDS: " . DBI::neat($s->{NUM_OF_FIELDS}), "\n";

$s = $h->selectall_arrayref(q{select * from #tmp});
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper($s), "\n";

$h->do(q/insert into martin2 select * from #tmp/);
$s = $h->selectall_arrayref(q{select * from martin2});
print Dumper($s), "\n";
```

Comment: Hi Bohica,  Thanks for the explanation. This was working perfectly fine for me too .but fails intermittently saying that 'Invalid object name '#temp' . This is the error message to be exact - DBD::ODBC::db selectall_hashref failed: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Invalid object name '#temp'. (SQL-42S02) [state was 42S02 now 42000].

Comment: I know of no reason why this would happen intermittently unless you had a bug in your code. That "was 42S02 now 42000" suggests more than one error was reported. If you can get a trace out of DBD::ODBC when it fails I /may/ be able to help.

Comment: Hi bohica, I have generated the trace . Its is a 2000 line file.Can you tell me how i can send across to you?

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot tell from this DBI trace if the select and insert are issued on the same connection handle. Take a look at tracing in the DBD::ODBC module and paste a DBD::ODBC trace instead. Basically (since it slightly differs depending on which version of DBI and DBD::ODBC you have) the easiest way is to set DBI_TRACE=15=x.log and export it then rerun failing script. You can pastbin it again I might be able to spot the problem. Trouble is this looks like a DBIx::Class based code which does a lot.

Comment: Hi bohica, Before doing this , i tried to print the hostnames where the failure occurs.  Our jobs are submitted in a grid infrastructure and i could see that the failure occurs only in a set of hosts which were added recently. I tried to run the job on the old set of hosts and it worked fine. I checked DBO , DBO.pm, Revisionable , Revisionable.pm and it all looked the same file. Anything i could check here ?

Comment: Hi Bohica , The problem was with DBD::ODBC module not being the latest , After putting the latest file , the problem did not occur

Comment: It would be useful for other is you mentioned the working versions of the modules and the non working ones. It would also be interesting to me as I maintain DBD::ODBC and I know of nothing I've changed in this area.

Comment: Hi - The DBD::ODBC file had $DBD::ODBC::VERSION = '1.30_5'; The latest DBD::ODBC and the not-latest DBD::ODBC that i mentioned before has the same line $DBD::ODBC::VERSION = '1.30_5'; - On investigating further - the not-latest file was manually modified by someone which caused this problem

Answer (score 1):

I was having this problem as well. I tried all of the above but it didnt matter. I stumbled upon this http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/80443-creating-temporary-table-select-into which solved my problem.

> What's happening is that ADO is opening a second connection behind
>   your back. This has really not anything to do with how you created the
>   table.
>
> The reason that ADO opens an extra connection, is because there are
>   rows waiting to be fetched on the first connection, so ADO cannot
>   submit a query on that connection.

I assume that Perl DBI is doing the same, so based on this assumption, here's what I did and it worked perfectly fine:

```
 my $sth = $dbh->prepare('Select name into #temp from NameTable');
 $sth->execute();
 $sth->fetchall_arrayref();
 $sth = $dbh->prepare('Select a.name, b.age from #temp a, AgeTable b where a.name = name');
 $sth->execute();
 my ($name,$age)
 $sth->bind_columns(\$name,\$age);
 while ( $sth->fetch())
 {
     # processing
 }
```

Comment: Actually it works intermittently. Changing #stale to ##stale solves it